# Python: Remove a Sublist Which Contains Only One Instance of an Item

Tags: python, list

everyone! Basically, I need to remove every sublist from a list which contains only one of any item - so long as that item itself is not one.

Here's an example: If I had this,

```
list = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 0), (1, 3), (2, 0), (0, 3)]
```

I would in turn want this:

```
list = [(0, 0), (1, 1)]
```

What I originally tried was:

```
for sublist in list:
    for item in sublist:
        if sublist.count(item) == 1 and item != 1:
            list.remove(sublist)
```

Unfortunately, this interfered with the cycling of the original for-loop (I think), so I would end up with things like: `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list` Any help appreciated.

EDIT: I'd like to apologize, (1, 3) should not be in the output! Sorry for the confusion, hopefully this program will be better at doing this than I am!

Comment: why you leave (1,3)? 3 exists only once in it. I'm not sure your explanation is clear enough

Comment: presumably if your 'sublists' which are actually tuples, contain '1', they are exempt from removal...?

Comment: Why does `(0,1)` get removed but `(1,3)` doesn't?

Comment: actually, he's getting the ValueError because he is deleting the same list multiple times - i.e. if you have (0,2), you first check for 0, it's there only once and not 1, so we ask to delete (0,2) from the list. then we check 2, and it's also in the list once and not 1, so we ask to delete (0,2) again, which is illegal. per one answer, use `break` to short-circuit after a match.

Comment: What @Corley Brigman is totally true, and one more if you delete your list element while iterating, there is chance of missing some element from testing. because the list size reduce when you delete, and the n element will move to n-1 place.

Comment: question looks to be uncleared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Copy the list before running the for loop, so the iterable don't get modified during the loop
2. Remove one `sublist` once and break, don't try to remove it twice.

Though I'm only getting `[(0, 0), (1, 1)]` but not `(1,3)` in output.

```
for sublist in list[:]:
    for item in sublist:
        if sublist.count(item) == 1 and item != 1:
             list.remove(sublist)
             break
```

Comment: Yes, that's the desired output. Sorry, made a mistake! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the task but changing list while iterating it is never a good idea.
try to copy it first and then iterate over the copy.

something like:

```
list_copy = list[:]
for sublist in list_copy:
    for item in sublist:
        if sublist.count(item) == 1 and item != 1:
            list.remove(sublist)
```

note that `list_copy = list` will copy the reference which means changing one list will change the other as well so you want to write `list_copy = list[:]`

P.S.
using the `list` type name as a variable is a very bad idea. try to use a different name.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this code is right for you:

```
list = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 0), (1, 3), (2, 0), (0, 3)]

out_list = [t for t in list if (t[0] == t[1]) or t.count(1) > 0]
```

This code generates a new list and then you can reassign it to your input list.
But the code above generates on your input:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (1, 3)]
```

Sorry, if I understand your task incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

### I must say your explanation of what the code does isn't clear.

You might want to move to while loops:

```
List = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 0), (1, 3), (2, 0), (0, 3)]
i = 0;
o = 0;
while i<len(List):
    while o<len(List[i]):
        if List[i].count(o) == 1 and List[i][o] != 1:
            List.remove(List[i])
        o+=1
    i+=1
    o=0;
print(List)
```

I got:

> [(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 3), (0, 3)]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter` function to filter a list. First, write a function that takes an element of your list and returns `True` if the element should be in the list, and `False` if not. Like this:

```
 def predicate(x):
    for item in x:
        if x.count(item) == 1 and item != 1:
            return False
    return True
```

Now, you can take your list (Don't call it `list`, since `list` is a function we will have to use in a second, and by calling something list you can't use said function)

```
l = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 0), (1, 3), (2, 0), (0, 3)]
```

And filter it with the predicate:

```
itr_res = filter(predicate,l)
```

Note, however that this returns an `iterable`, and not a list. You probably want a list, so use the `list` function to construct one from the `iterable`.

```
res = list(itr_res)
```

this gives the resulting list:

```
[(0,0),(1,1)]
```

As others have noted, it is hard to figure out exactly what you want your function to filter. Your code does one thing, your example and other and your description is vague. You can try to play around with the predicate function until you get it to do what you actually want